# json parse isse with nested response reactjs

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a json response

```
[{
"province": "abc",
"county": "aa",
"timeline": {
    "cases": {
        "4/11/20": 4,
        "4/12/20": 5
    },
    "recover": {
        "4/11/20": 0,
        "4/12/20": 1
    }
}
}]
```

Although I am able to get "county" value but I am not able to go into timline data.Its either giving me undefined issue or giving [obejct Object] as log. Below I my code.

```
parseTimeLineData(resData)
  {
   let  timeLine = [];
    resData.map(data =>
    {
     let dd = data.timeline;
      Object.keys(dd).map((key, i) => {
      var one = {key}
      alert(one);
      var value = dd[key]
      })
    });  
  }
```

My requirement is to parse the cases and recover nodes and save them in separate array to be used further. Also need to know how to only fetch first index values out of a big array.

Comment: "or giving [obejct Object] as log", because the `value` in your function is an object?

Comment: So how could I parse the inner most val and fetch key and value from it.

Comment: What is the shape of your desired data? How will you use it? Please provide this information. You can update your question.

Comment: @devserkan I guess below I got the answer. I am new to react, so not familier with many functions it has. like JSON. stringify

Comment: This is not related to React, `JSON.stringify` belongs to JS. If I'm not mistaken with the provided answer you get an array of array, which I think is not the desired output.

Comment: Yes I solve part of my problem. I need to fetch and store key and values in seperate array so that I can use them seperately.

Comment: Again, please update your question and explain the desired output. Just give an example of how the data should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213663/discussion-between-kshitij-and-devserkan).

Answer (score 2):

**Use JSON.stringify**

```js
[{
"province": "abc",
"county": "aa",
"timeline": {
    "cases": {
        "4/11/20": 4,
        "4/12/20": 5
    },
    "recover": {
        "4/11/20": 0,
        "4/12/20": 1
    }
}
}].map(data => Object.keys(data.timeline).map(item => alert(JSON.stringify(data.timeline[item]))))
```

Comment: its giving me values now.Thanks.. I am new to react. So I dont know much about JSON.stringify() it solves the issue.

Comment: Sorry I got to know srtringify is only to see the result. We can use it for getting and fetching vals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure how do you want those arrays since you haven't provided a concrete example. So, I'm blindly guessing that there will be other objects in your `data` and somehow you want to accumulate `cases` and `recover` values somehow, then use those in the future. So, here is an example of `reduce`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    province: "abc",
    county: "aa",
    timeline: {
      cases: {
        "4/11/20": 4,
        "4/12/20": 5,
      },
      recover: {
        "4/11/20": 0,
        "4/12/20": 1,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    province: "xyz",
    county: "bb",
    timeline: {
      cases: {
        "4/13/20": 40,
        "4/14/20": 50,
      },
      recover: {
        "4/13/20": 10,
        "4/14/20": 5,
      },
    },
  },
];

function parseTimeLineData(resData) {
  return resData.reduce((acc, data) => {
    const newCases = Object.entries(
      data.timeline.cases
    ).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

    const newRecovers = Object.entries(
      data.timeline.recover
    ).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

    acc.cases = !acc.cases ? newCases : [...acc.cases, ...newCases];
    acc.recover = !acc.recover ? newRecovers : [...acc.recover, ...newRecovers];

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const reducedValues = parseTimeLineData(data);
console.log(reducedValues);
```

I'm not quite sure if this is the structure you want but I am dropping this as an example.